# $http_referer ведет себя как $document_uri

Tags: nginx

Кусок шаблона с инклудом:

```
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
      <div class="ym-wbox">
        <!--# set var="panel"
          value="<!--# include virtual='/panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=$http_referer' -->" -->
        <!--# echo var="panel" encoding="none" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Формат лога nginx'а:

```
log_format  subtimed  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                      '"INC $uri$is_args$args" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"
```

Локейшн в nginx'е:

```
location /panel/ {
            internal;
            ssi  on;
            proxy_set_header        Host panel.domain.zone;
            proxy_method            GET;
            proxy_pass              http://panel.domain.zone/;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_connect_timeout   1s;
            proxy_send_timeout      2s;
            proxy_read_timeout      2s;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;
            log_subrequest on;
    }
```

Открываем страницу http://devel.domain.zone в новой вкладке.
Смотрим запись в лог:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:29:31 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=http://devel.domain.zone" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Переходим на страницу http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102
Смотрим лог:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:30:29 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Т.е. выходит, что `$http_referer` почему-то ведет себя как `$document_uri` ???
Да, и при подстановке `$document_uri` в инклуд в логе nginx'а видно что-то такое:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:30:29 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=/ga/ga.js" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Кто-нибудь понимает, как это происходит? В какой момент вычисляется `$document_uri`? Как передается `$http_referer` в инклуде: вычисленным или именем переменной?

Answer (score 1):

> Кто-нибудь понимает, как это происходит?

начать стоит с разбирательства, откуда в логе при запросе `http://devel.domain.zone` (т.е., при обращении к корню сайта) вдруг ни с того ни с сего появляется не только *url* (`/panel`), но ещё и аргументы.

из приведённого фрагмента конфигурации такое поведение никак не следует. вероятно, вы опустили существенную для ответа информацию. как из конфигурации *nginx-а*, так и из конфигурации *http-сервера*, обслуживающего сайт *panel.domain.zone*, куда *nginx* проксирует *http-запросы*.